# Not able to install openpyxl in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am using Windows 7 64 bit. When I install openpyxl library from the link below, it is a file.tar.gz file.

First concern is I am unable to extract this file? Since I am unable to extract the file, I can't install the same.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: `pip install openpyxl`?

Comment: Gives me the error... this is what I do. open cmd.. go to python27/Scripts folder... and run pip install openpyxl.. give me the error retrying.. retrying for like 4 times and later.."Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl "

Comment: ^ Please edit the question to explain the problems you had. As it stands, there is no clear problem statement, and the question is likely to close.

Answer (score 0):

Normal unzipping software will not work with .tar.gz files. I suggest you use [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html)

However, you can use the command `pip install openpyxl`, which may need pillow library (Use `pip install Pillow`)

Comment: Thanks for your response, You mean without downloading and extracting I can go ahead and use pip to install openpyxl ?

Comment: You do not need to download anything. Use the command in your python console of choice (command line or anaconda)

Comment: I get this error when I install pillow first.File  "<stdin>", Line1... SyntaxError: invalid syntax